# does not contain a defination for 'Show' and no accessible extension method 'Show' accepting a frist argument of type 'Page'

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

due to my less knowledge, i cant solve my small problems,  my books can help me too. therefore. I need your help and appreciate it, ofcourse too!

Problem: i just wanna jump from one page to the next page! but the Show() and Close() methods show the exactly same error. Perhaps something is missing in Registration Page?

[image]

Thanks alot for your reply!

Comment: The error indicates that the `Registration` class does not expose methods named `Show` or `Close`. To troubleshoot, check why you expect these methods to exist, and then verify that reasoning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods `Show` and `Close` exists in the class `Window` and in classes based on it. I̶f̶ ̶R̶e̶g̶i̶s̶t̶r̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶i̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶"̶P̶a̶g̶e̶"̶,̶ ̶h̶o̶w̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶w̶r̶o̶t̶e̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶n̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶r̶o̶l̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶s̶o̶m̶e̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶a̶i̶n̶e̶r̶,̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶e̶x̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶ ̶`̶G̶r̶i̶d̶`̶,̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶p̶e̶r̶t̶y̶ ̶`̶V̶i̶s̶i̶b̶i̶l̶i̶t̶y̶`̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶v̶i̶s̶i̶b̶l̶e̶,̶ ̶h̶i̶d̶d̶e̶n̶ ̶o̶r̶ ̶c̶o̶l̶l̶a̶p̶s̶e̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶.̶ ̶

E̶l̶s̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶a̶d̶d̶ ̶m̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶n̶f̶o̶ ̶a̶b̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶"̶r̶e̶g̶i̶s̶t̶r̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶"̶ ̶c̶l̶a̶s̶s̶.̶ ̶F̶o̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶g̶o̶ ̶o̶v̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶.̶c̶s̶ ̶f̶i̶l̶e̶

Upd: Ok, I made a mistake, when wrote without test. I described your problem in more details:

Your class `Registration` based on `Page` class. Class `Page` based on class `Control`. Therefore, that your class `Registration` it's not the `Window` and you can't open it in new window. If you want realize many-windows app, then you should change base class on `Registration` from `Page` to `Window` in XAML editor. Else you should init `Frame` to work with pages and add him in your container in `MainWindow`. Further you must use the "Navigate" method of the "Frame" class. How I see possible solution your error:

```
private Dictionary<string, Page> pages;
private Frame frame;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    InitPages();
}

private void InitPages()
{
    pages = new Dictionary<string, Page>();//dictionary for access to your pages
    var registration = new Registration();//registration init
    registration.Background = Brushes.LemonChiffon;
    pages.Add("reg", registration);//add your page in dictionary for 
    //further access to this page
    this.frame = new Frame();//frame init
    this.container.Children.Add(frame);//add this frame in container
    //container is Grid in MainWindow
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    frame.Navigate(pages["reg"]);
}
```

It should be understood that this is not an example of the correctness of the code, but only a possible solution to the your problem!

Comment: hey Lenkoras, thanks for your best solution!! I am still struggling with this part! couldn't get it! [ this.container.Children.Add(frame); ], the children shows same error